# Capturing all of N's Pokemon

Tags: pokemon-fifth-generation

Playing through my game of White2, I encountered a Pokemon which I thought was shiny due to the way it appeared in the wild. When I caught it, there was a note that "it appears to have a different trainer ID" or something to that effect. When I looked at it, it said the OT was "N". So that leads to the following questions:

1. How many Pokemon have the OT tag of "N"?
2. Where can I catch them all?
3. Can you catch his legendary dragon?
4. Do you receive anything for capturing them all?
5. Do the captured pokemon gain the normal experience boost as traded pokemon?
6. If I accidentally make them faint, can they be encountered again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pokemon with N's trainer ID appear after using the Memory Link feature with Pokemon Black / White.

1. Here's [a list](http://www.serebii.net/black2white2/nspokemon.shtml) of Pokemon with N's trainer ID.
2. The list also includes their locations.
3. You can catch his legendary dragon by visiting the ruins of his castle after completing the game and defeating him in a battle, then taking the stone you receive to Dragonspiral Tower.
4. You don't receive anything for catching all of the Pokemon with his trainer ID, but catching his legendary dragon will enable you to catch Kyurem in the Giant Chasm.
5. Yes
6. Yes

Sources:

- Serebii.net: [N's Pokemon](http://www.serebii.net/black2white2/nspokemon.shtml), [Legendary Pokemon](http://www.serebii.net/black2white2/legendary.shtml)
- GameFAQs: [FAQ about N's Pokemon](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/661226-pokemon-black-version-2/64354138)

Answer (score 0):

Two important additions to @DustinMartin's answer:

- **All of N's pokémon has 30 IVs!**
- All of them are male

This can be used as a genetic breeding advantage to get a higher IV's for any pokémon (with genderless and legendaries being exceptions).

Source: [Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/N%27s_Pok%C3%A9mon)

Comment: This is a good addition but it doesn't address anything from the question, really.

Comment: @Vemonus You're right, but it would certainly be of use for the OP (and others searching for this thread). It is the *only* thing I use N's pokémon for.